# How to return the not-cancelled tasks from Task.WhenAll execution

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I have a list of tasks that are cancellable; they have their `CancellationTokenSource`. Their cancellation is independent of others. I want to return all the not-canceled tasks from `Task.WhenAll`.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

/** some code here **/

var done = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // This throws an OperationCanceledException,
                                      // when at least one task is cancelled.
```

There are questions in the StackOverflow "how to cancel a task inside a task," but this question here is not that.

Comment: As was said [in the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577346), you can't do that with a _single_ CancellationToken. You'd need one per task.

Comment: You mean tasks that have completed prior to cancellation?

Comment: @gunr2171 I already have one cancellationsource per task, I would like to keep each task throwing OperationCanceledException. The request in this question is to how to handle in the Task,WhenAll, or other way, to process only the not-cancelled tasks

Comment: @the.Doc prior and after, consider the taks: t1, t2, t3, t4. They are independent in a sense they have their own CancellationTokenSource, but they throw OperationCanceledException by design. Lets say t2 got cancelled. I would like to be able to finish t1,t2,t3,t4.

Comment: What's wrong with `tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCanceled)`

Comment: Do you just want to keep retrying to complete all tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the `Task.WhenAll` task in a `Task` variable, so that you can add a `catch` block that handles exclusively the [`IsCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled) case.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

/** some code here **/

Task whenAll = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Task<string>[] successfullyCompletedTasks;

try
{
    await whenAll;
    successfullyCompletedTasks = tasks.ToArray();
}
catch when (whenAll.IsCanceled)
{
    successfullyCompletedTasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCanceled).ToArray();
}

// Make sure that our assumptions do not contradict the reality
Debug.Assert(successfullyCompletedTasks.All(t => t.IsCompletedSuccessfully));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retry the rest of the tasks by looping `Task.WhenAll`

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

/** some code here **/
var notCanceled = tasks;
do
{
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(notCanceled);
        break;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        notCanceled = notCanceled.Where(t => !t.IsCanceled).ToArray();
    }
} while (notCanceled.Any())
```